# Scanning html DIVs from C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I need to scan through a set of DIV collection and get the DIV IDs accordingly. Here's a piece of DIV collection in HTML.

```
<div id="rack12" rel="12" class="">
<span class="empty"></span>
    <input type="hidden" id="GUID" value="">
</div>
<div id="rack13" rel="13" class="">
<span class="full"></span>
    <div id="d92eec4f-2674-e311-9422-00155d04941f" rel="430.00 12.00 5 d92eec4f-2674-e311-9422-00155d04941f" class="selectedEquipment" style="height:105px;">
        <p>IBM SPARC 5000u | 430.00W | 12.00Kg | 5RU </p>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="GUID" value="d92eec4f-2674-e311-9422-00155d04941f">
</div>
```

So, for example, I need to find out which DIV ID (rack12 or rack13) contains this GUID *d92eec4f-2674-e311-9422-00155d04941f*. After that I need to do some logic and update the properties of that GUID in C# codebehind. By the way, these DIVs are generated from C# dynamically.

I have some difficulties in using javascript inside C#. Can advise me if there's an easy way to implement?

Comment: you need to figure out which parts you need done on client side with javascript and what parts need to be done on the server with c#.

Comment: Save your effort and use Html Agility Pack (Sample Code: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples). for your case, use xpath to iterate through the `<divs>` and get the attribute `id`

Answer (score 0):

Add `runat="server"` attribute to the DIVs ("rack12" and "rack13"). Then you could manipulate them in code behind using ID or ClientID as a server control.

Comment: I'm not able to add runat="server" because these DIVs are generated dynamically. When I add this, I got the error. Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste the code where you add these DIVs dynamically, then I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Jquery , I havent understood exactly what you need, Still here is an example

```
         $('div').each(function(e){ 
            var obj = $(this);
               obj.find("input").each(function(e){
                   var inputobj = $(this);
                   alert(inputobj.val());  //Here You will have input obj , U can  use your code  part here
              });
        });
```

Here is a Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/AmarnathRShenoy/ykPg4/1/